# Centering the elements in a div using css responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which consists of 3 more divs inside as below.

What I'm trying to do here when the window is resized or per say if the page is being viewed in a mobile then the paragraph p tag disappears and only anchor tag a remains and icons will be displayed. I'm able to hide the paragraph tag but unable to align the a tag icons horizontally and at the center of the page. Kindly suggest me ideas and let me know if I should include some more info. Thanks.

Here is the HTML & CSS associated with the div

```html
<div class="container" id="footer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 footerSections paddingBottom20">
      <div class="footerProfile">
        <img src="images/avatar.jpg" id="avatar" height="100" width="100" style="float:left;" />
        <p style="text-align: justify;">Deepak is a graduate in Computer Science. In my free time I like to learn new technologies and hangout with my friends.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 footerSections">
      <div class="footerSocialLinks">
        <div> <a href="#" target="_blank" style="float:left"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw fa-2x"></i></a>

          <p class="desktop-only">Follow <a href="#" target="_blank">@imadistack</a> for web development</p>
        </div>
        <div> <a href="#" target="_blank" style="float:left"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw fa-2x"></i></a>

          <p class="desktop-only">Follow <a href="#" target="_blank">@imadistack</a> for web development</p>
        </div>
        <div> <a href="#" target="_blank" style="float:left"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw fa-2x"></i></a>

          <p class="desktop-only">Follow <a href="#" target="_blank">@imadistack</a> for web development</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 footerSections">
      <div class="footerMenu">
        <dl> <dt><a href="#aboutMe">ABOUT</a></dt>

          <dd class="desktop-only">Learn about Deepak’s skills and workflow</dd> <dt><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></dt>

          <dd class="desktop-only">View Deepak’s design &amp; front-end development work</dd> <dt><a href="#skills">SKILLS</a></dt>

          <dd class="desktop-only">Learn about Deepak's skills</dd> <dt><a href="#education">EDUCATION</a></dt>

          <dd class="desktop-only">Learn about Deepak's education</dd> <dt><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></dt>

          <dd class="desktop-only">Send a message or project request to Deepak</dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.footerSections{
     padding:0 30px 0 30px;
    }

    .footerSocialLinks ul{
        list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;
    }

    @media (min-width: 640px) 
    {
        .desktop-only{
            display:block;
        }

    }

    @media (max-width: 640px) 
    {
        .desktop-only{
            display:none;
        }

        #footer{
            padding: 40px 35px 40px 35px;
        }

        .footerSections{
            padding:10px;
        }

        .footerMenu dt {
            text-align:center;
            padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
        }
        .footerSocailLinks {
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
        }

    }
```

Update: I did use media queries and that is how I was able to hide the p tag.

Here is a link to the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/598/

You would see the twitter icons are on the left side of the page. They should be centered when the window size is reduced or in mobile view.

Comment: Just a site note: you shouldn't be using the `<i></i>` tag, apply this css style instead: `font-style: italic;`

Comment: Can you create fiddle for your problem? I cant understand what you relly need.

Comment: @RicoOcepek The i tag is for font awesome and not italics. I'm using the font awesome library for social media icons

Comment: @DawidUrbanski I have added a fiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got 3 problems here.

1. The `float:left` of your anchor tag. It makes your element ignore all `text-align`s from parent containers.
2. The `display: inline-block` of your `.footerSocialLinks`, you should either leave it to the standard `display: block` or add a `width` (eg `width: 100%`) to the element.
3. You need to set `whitespace: no-wrap` on your `.footerSocialLinks` and `display:inline-block` on the divisions inside it in order to prevent them from jumping into a new line.

Additionally there is a typo in your current stylesheet ".footerSocailLinks".

Try the following style sheet:

```
.footerSocialLinks{

    text-align:center;

    whitespace:no-wrap;

 } 

.footerSocialLinks > div{

    display:inline-block;

    text-align: center;

}
```

I tried this in you fiddle and it does what it should do. Just place the stylesheet above inside your media query.

And don't forget to remove the `float`s from your anchor tags!

Comment: Hi Rico Ocepek, The twitter icons are still getting aligned left. I have updated the code in my site but there was no change. I'm I missing something?

Comment: You also need to remove the `float:left` from your `a` tags in your html code if you haven't done so.

Comment: It did center the icons but they are aligned vertically as shown in this link: http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/?u=http://madistack.com This link has the mobile view for my page. I want them to be aligned horizontally and centered. Once again thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh, so you want the 3 icons to be in a row?

Comment: Yes, They would be vertically aligned in desktop view but in mobile view they would be in a row. Check www.madistack.com for desktop view

Comment: Thank you so much Rico. It worked :). If you dont mind I would like to ask one more question. If you see my page on www.madistack.com while reducing the size gradually at one point before the mobile view kicks in  the twitter icons are going into the previous div. i.e the icons are getting mixed with text in the previous div. Is there any fix for that.

Comment: No problem :)  I can't test it right now but I'll check on that later.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help. Do check it when you get some free time.

Comment: Sorry for the late response..

The problem here is that the image of yourself is bigger than its container and so your icons below seem to jump arround as they like.
Just add a `min-height` in the same amount as your image's `height` (`100px`) to this container division: 
`<div class="col-md-4 footerSections paddingBottom20">`   And don't forget to +1 if it helps :)

Comment: Thanks Rico it worked. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation too up vote the answer. But I'll mark it for sure once I gain some.

Comment: You're welcome!  Oh didn't think of that, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to toggle blocks of CSS based on the client size, for instance:

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    .desktop-only { 
         display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was how to center the anchor tag, not how to hide the `.desktop-only` stuff.

Comment: Given the title and the original, unedited question, that wasn't entirely clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center an anchor tag, you wouldn't be able to simply use the text-align center on the anchor as it is an inline element by default. There are 2 possibilities to center an anchor tag:

First - Apply text-align center to a parent element

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <a href="#">Anchor Tag</a>
</div>
```

Second - Change the anchor to be display: block then the text-align: center can be applied

```
<div>
    <a href="#" style="display: block; text-align: center">Anchor Tag</a>
</div>
```

Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/kwf8dsoa/

One of those options, paired with media queries should get the job done for you

Comment: Hi thanks for the info. However my question was I'm floating 3 anchor tags left so that they line up side by side which is conflicting with my purpose of making those 3 centered. Kindly check this fiddle and try to resize increase or decrease.https://jsfiddle.net/kwf8dsoa/1/